# NoMethodError: undefined method `lookup' for Puppet:Module

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, puppet

I'm having some issues with my rspec-puppet unit tests. I continually receive the following error. I've included my puppet class manifest and spec test. I set up the testing env using the instructions on http://rspec-puppet.com/.. The errors are below.

puppet manifest

```
# Cups class for stopping and disabling cups
class cups {

  service { 'cupsd':
    ensure => stopped,
    enable => false,
  }
}
```

spec test

```
require "#{File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'..','spec_helper.rb')}"

describe 'cups' do
  it { should contain_service('cupsd').with_ensure('stopped') }
  it { should contain_service('cupsd').with_enable('false') }
end
```

Failures:

```
  1) cups cups service
    Failure/Error: it { should contain_service('cupsd').with_ensure('stopped') }
     NoMethodError:
      undefined method `lookup' for Puppet:Module
      # ./spec/classes/cups_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

 2) cups cups service
    Failure/Error: it { should contain_service('cupsd').with_enable('false') }
     NoMethodError:
      undefined method `lookup' for Puppet:Module
      # ./spec/classes/cups_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: In which file did you put that `rspec` code?

Comment: I resolved this issue by using the bundler and specifically setting the gems and versions required by my spec test. Running 'bundle exec rspec spec' in the module directory successfully ran this spec test.  I do however receive multiple deprecation warnings for legacy RSpect matcher protocols but the test works.